# Model.updateOne() returning `{ acknowledged: false }`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to append an object to an array in an existing mongodb document (`categories: []`). The server is able to receive the request body but it gives `{ acknowledged: false }` when I log the update `updatedCategory`. The document isnt updated either.

seller.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const Menu = require('../models/menu');

router.put('/menu/initiate', async(req, res) => {

    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.user_email})
    const user_id = user._id.valueOf()

    const updatedCategory = await Menu.updateOne({user_id: user_id}, {$push: {categories: {category: req.body.categoryName, items: []}}})
    console.log(updatedCategory)

    res.status(200).send('category updated')
})

module.exports = router;
```

Menu Model:

```js
const Menu = new mongoose.Schema({
    "user_id": {
        "type": "String"
    },
    "menu": {
        "categories": {
            "type": [
                "Mixed"
            ]
        }
    }
},
{collection: 'menus'});
```

Comment: Perhaps try to show your sample document and also the provided data for update.

Comment: Calling `valueOf` on the user ID stands out to me. Is `matchedCount` non-zero when you log `updatedCategory`?

Comment: Added the menu model. It doesnt show me a `matchedCount`. All it gives is `{acknowledged: false}`

Answer (score 1):

On the Menu model, the `categories` field is nested under the `menu` field. In your update document, it is treated as a top-level field, which doesn't match with the defined Schema. Because the update you're trying to perform doesn't correspond to a field in the schema, Mongoose doesn't attempt an update at all. That's likely why we aren't seeing other fields we might expect when attempting an update, such as `matchedCount`.

I believe the update will work if you make sure that you are pushing to `menu.categories` like this:

```
const updatedCategory = await Menu.updateOne({user_id: user_id}, {$push: {"menu.categories": {category: req.body.categoryName, items: []}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the mongoose doesn't find the `categories` path in the mongoose schema for the `$push` update. If the [strict](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) option of the schema is enabled, mongoose will make this update fail and return `{acknowledged: false}`.

You should update the `menu.categories` path, it's an array of `Mixed`. The correct code is like below:

```
const r = await Menu.updateOne({ user_id: '1' }, { $push: { 'menu.categories': { category: 'a', items: [] } } });
```

---

*"mongoose": "^7.3.1"*

**Further explain:**

This `{acknowledged: false}` result was returned by Mongoose, not the MongoDB server. You can find it in [`_updateThunk()`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/b336ed83a02e1fa627b3997b4fa3b88754abd99e/lib/query.js#L3854) function.

```
//...

this._update = this._castUpdate(this._update, this._mongooseOptions.overwrite);
if (this._update == null || Object.keys(this._update).length === 0) {
    return { acknowledged: false };
}
```

If you disable the `strict` option for schema.

```
const menuSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        user_id: String,
        menu: {
            categories: {
                type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed],
            },
        },
    },
    { collection: 'menus', strict: false },
);
const Menu = mongoose.model('menu', menuSchema);
```

The update will be performed but the updated document probably is not what you want.

```
// seed
await Menu.create([{ user_id: '1', menu: { categories: [] } }]);
// test
const r = await Menu.updateOne({ user_id: '1' }, { $push: { categories: { category: 'a', items: [] } } });
console.log(r);
```

Debug logs:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

The update can be performed.

Check the documents:

```
Atlas atlas-zy5qpa-shard-0 [primary] test> db.menus.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64a7af0c71ea64e347d15bd0"),
    user_id: '1',
    menu: { categories: [] },
    __v: 0,
    categories: [ { category: 'a', items: [] } ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, MongoDB adds a `categoies` new field to the document with an array value rather than updating the `menu.categoies`.